# How to access mobx object in webpack bundle(js) from external

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mobx, mobx-react

I'd like to access an object (i.e. MOBX object) which is declared in a JSX file. I used webpack to bundle all my jsx files in one output file (bundle.js). But I want to access some functions and objects in the bundle file. How we can do this?

My webconfig.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var buildDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/scripts');
var scriptsDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts');

var config = {
    entry: {
        main: scriptsDir + '/app'
    },
    output: {
        path: buildDir,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'MyLibrary'
    },
    externals: {
    },
    debug: true,
    // Important! Do not remove ''. If you do, imports without
    // an extension won't work anymore!
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              // Enable caching for improved performance during development
              // It uses default OS directory by default. If you need
              // something more custom, pass a path to it.
              // I.e., babel?cacheDirectory=<path>
              loaders: ['babel?cacheDirectory'],
              exclude: /(node_modules)/
          }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

JSX file

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var mobx = require('mobx');
var mobxReact = require('mobx-react');
var mobxDevtools = require('mobx-react-devtools');

mobx.useStrict(true);

var todoFactory = function (title) {
    var todo = {
        id: Math.random(),
        toggleStatus: mobx.action(function toggleStatus() {
            todo.finished = !todo.finished;
        })
    };
    mobx.extendObservable(todo,
        {
            title: title,
            finished: false
        }
    );
    return todo;
};

var todoListFactory = function () {
    var todoList = {
        addTodo: mobx.action(function addTodo(todo) {
            todoList.todos.push(todo);
        }),
        addTodos: mobx.action(function addTodos(todos) {
            todoList.todos = todoList.todos.concat(todos);
        })
    };

    mobx.extendObservable(todoList, {
        todos: [],
        unfinishedTodoCount: function () {
            return todoList.todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return !todo.finished;
            }).length;
        }
    });

    return todoList;
};

var TodoListView = mobxReact.observer(function TodoListView() {
    var devtools = mobxDevtools ? React.createElement(mobxDevtools.default) : null;

    var listItems = this.props.todoList.todos.map(function (todo) {
        return React.createElement(TodoView, { todo: todo, key: todo.id });
    });

    return React.createElement('div', null,
        devtools,
        React.createElement('ul', null, listItems),
        'Tasks left: ' + this.props.todoList.unfinishedTodoCount
    );
}
);

var TodoView = mobxReact.observer(
    React.createClass({
        displayName: 'TodoView',
        render: function () {
            var todo = this.props.todo;
            return React.createElement('li', null,
                React.createElement('input', {
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    checked: todo.finished,
                    onClick: this.selectHandler
                }),
                todo.title
            );
        },
        selectHandler: function () {
            this.props.todo.toggleStatus();
        }
    })
);

var store = todoListFactory();

store.addTodos([todoFactory('Get Coffee'), todoFactory('Write simpler code')]);
store.todos[0].toggleStatus(true);

var Practice = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <TodoListView todoList={store} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Practice;
```

My goal is to be able to access the store object externally. Something like **'MyLibrary.store'**. How could this be possible?

Thanks,
Marvin

Comment: You could put the store on the `window` object if you have to. `var store = todoListFactory(); window.todoListStore = store;`

Comment: @Tholle thanks! this is straightforward solution I also initially thought of and could probably the catch all solution. However, I'm inclined to implement in the same manner as answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if the store object is not defined in an entry point file, then in an entry point you should import and export the store object.

**// entry_point.js**

```
...
var store = require('./file_with_store').store;
exports.store = store;
```

after that, since you have added `library: 'MyLibrary'` property to the webpack config, you can access **MyLibrary.store**

2) if the store object allready in entry point file, then just add:

```
exports.store = store;
```

Comment: thanks! #1 is my scenario with small difference. The 'store' in './file_with_store' also called from different file called './the_store'. Although I can now see the 'MyLibrary.store' but it is undefined. Do you have an idea? I also add exports.store = store in '.file_with_store' but no luck.

Comment: Clarification too, this line var store = require('./file_with_store').store; returns 'store' = undefined.

Comment: @marvs could you provide gist or repo of your code.

Comment: here's the gist location of the 3 files involved. https://gist.github.com/marvinvperez/b7603e61dd5bc6665764e40a9f6eecbf

Comment: @marvs SampleStore module is the singleton, therefore in entry.js, you can import SampleStore directly from SampleStore.js. : `var samplestore = require("./SampleStore"); exports.samplestore = samplestore`

Comment: you are correct. I tried that earlier by importing directly and that works. But I think the preferred solution is if I can get away of singleton. if I need to redo samplestore to make it not a singleton I am fine with that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @marvs do you want import from home.js?

Comment: sorry, did you mean instead of using var samplestore I'll use import samplestore from ... ?

Comment: sorry, i mean import through require, but if you want you can use es6 modules

Comment: in order to make working your gist , you need to add `module.exports.samplestore=samplestore;` in home.js, after `module.exports = Home;` -

Comment: right now we're not yet ready to use es6. For now, I think I can live with importing the store directly from entry.js. But I'm still looking forward to see a solution to avoid it and use the samplestore declared in home.js. I will accept your answer now, and thanks for the help. But let me know if you have other suggestion.

Comment: @marvs check my previous comment

Comment: Oh really cool! that solves the problem. So I guess when I change the samplestore module as non-singleton this solution still work. That's awesome! Thanks much @Utro.